# SVN SSL handshake failed: SSL error: bad packet length

Tags: java, svn, ssl, maven, maven-release-plugin

We are getting the following error with SVN and Maven. We use maven release plugin to create a tag in svn

svn: OPTIONS of 'https://XXXXXXXXX/trunk': SSL handshake failed: SSL error: bad packet length

maven command use is buildnumber:create build-helper:parse-version  release:prepare release:perform

Any thoughts on this SSL issue?

Answer (score 2):

Since the Apache Maven will use the svn client which is installed in our OS.
We should ensure that our svn client is worked properly.

1.Firstly we should ensure that we have a svn client installed.

2.We can use the following command for storing the accepted root certificate.

```
svn list https://your_host/path/to/repo

The system will prompt you to accept it temporary or permanent. 
Please choose/type 'p' for permanent.
```

If the above command is not completed or there are some error, please follow this as an alternative.

Copy *the root certificate* and choose to store at one of the following folder

Global

```
Unix:
   /etc/subversion/auth/svn.ssl.server
Windows:
   %ALLUSERSPROFILE%\Application Data\Subversion\auth\svn.ssl.server
```

Per user

```
Unix:
   ~/.subversion/auth/svn.ssl.server
Windows:
   %APPDATA%\Subversion\auth\svn.ssl.server
```

Regarding to the chosen root folder, */what/ever/subversion*, We will see the file named "*servers*". Please open and put the following line.

```
ssl-authority-files =/what/ever/subversion/auth/svn.ssl.server/your_root.cer
```

3.We can verify the completion by using the same command as the following: -

```
svn list https://your_host/path/to/repo
```

The system will print the files inside your repository.

I hope this may help to achieve the requirement.

Regards,

Charlee Ch.

Answer (score 0):

Are you using an old Subversion client/server? If it's a 1.4.6, you might be hitting a bug in Subversion (as describer [here](http://bugs.debian.org/cgi-bin/bugreport.cgi?bug=480041)). You might want to try upgrading both the client and the server, if you're using a version that old.

If not, the other option would probably be that you might have to add the server's key to your keystore.